# Double Quote & String Escape Hell in R

Tags: r

Can someone shine some light on this issue I'm having? I'm trying to issue a system command from inside R. I've whittled it down to the simplest possible example:

What I want the terminal to see is

```
$ my_cmd --options "my options"
```

So I try this:

```
my_cmd <- paste0(
  "my_cmd ",
  "--options \"my options\" "
)

system(my_cmd)
```

No matter what I do, the command always comes out with the escape character included!? It's driving me slightly nuts. What am I doing wrong?

```
$ my_cmd --options \"my options\"
```

Comment: Have you tried single quotes (`'--options "my options"'`)?

Comment: Yip. It's crazy. The double quote gets replaced by an escaped double quote!

Comment: Have you looked at `?shQuote`?

Comment: And with the escapes, does the `system(` command run as you expect?, in as much as the escapes are 'decoration' for R printing and the like. Does it interfere with `system (` execution? My experience with lapply(..., system) suggests the more quotes the better, <- paste0('"', what I want to play with, ""'), that looks terrible for \, but runs reliably.

Comment: @Chris, In my actual code, it does break my command unfortunately.

Comment: @MikaelJagan No - Looks like it doesn't do anything though...

Comment: What command are you using in your actual code and might `sprintf(` help to clarify to the underlying `system(` command?

Comment: Maybe `system2('my_cmd', args = c('--options', '"my options"')`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Very interesting suggestion. 'ls' works fine. But when I try and run 'aws lambda invoke' etc , it seems to vanish into a black hole. No error or success response, although default stderr & stdout are the R console...

Comment: Please provide an actual command as a minimal reproducible example. Escaped quotes seem to work just fine on my system.

Comment: @monkey You can redirect stdout and stderr to files eventually getting some information on what is happening, , see the function's arguments in `help("system2")`.

Comment: In my case the escaped quotes appear only on the screen but did not go to the system call. `system("echo \"Hello World\"")` gives `Hello World`. If `"` would have been escaped it would have returned `"Hello World"` what I get when is use `system("echo \\\"Hello World\\\"")`